# Why don't I receive notifications of new privileges?

Tags: support, notifications, privileges

I want to be notified of new privileges I receive so I can kick the tires. However, it doesn't look like I am receiving these notifications. I would have received the "view close votes" privilege sometime in the past 3 weeks, but looking back through my "Achievements" feed I do not see any notification. Nor do I remember seeing one.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because you already have more reputation on another site in the Stack Exchange network, and are supposed to 'know' that you can view close votes (on your own questions) at 250 reputation. The details are described in [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68264/295232) but it's already six years old so I don't know if it's up to date (for instance, it doesn't show the new privilege levels at 5k, 15k, 20k and 25k).

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Keeps it simple and less spammy I guess.